# Problema al seleccionar una n de números aleatorios de arrays en un dataframe con reposición de números con python

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un dataframe de 11 columnas donde cada fila (filas=800) tiene un array de len=38000 de números tipo float64.
Quiero seleccionar una n=1000 de los números que hay en cada fila de todas las columnas con reposición.
Tengo algo así:

```
   col1                        col2                      col3 ....
  [-0.0359075218              [-0.0703638196            -0.1194577292
  -0.09805922210000001       -0.085132733              -0.1256169379
   -0.1091913655...           -0.0447771102...         -0.1277798414...
```

Cada columna tiene 800 arrays como los del ejemplo, cada array tiene 38000 números necesito extraer aleatoriamente 1000 de cada array.

He hecho esto:

```
n=1000
df['rand_sample'] = [np.random.choice(j, size=n, replace=True) for i 
 in df for j in df[i]]
```

Y me da este error:
ValueError: Length of values (8000) does not match length of index (800)

Entiendo el error, pero no sé por qué se produce.

Gracias por la ayuda!!

Xavier,

Answer (score 0):

El error surje cuando intentas asignar lo que te resulta de tus 800 filas por los 1000 numeros=8000 en las 800 filas.
Te recomiendo hacer una nueva columna en el DataFrame y ahi colocar las nuevas filas generadas.
Si estuvieras generando tus datos de esta manera, podrias intentar lo siguiente:

```
data = np.random(800,11,38000)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#TU CODIGO
n=1000
df['rand_sample'] = [np.random.choice(j, size=n, replace=True) for i 
 in df for j in df[i]]

#Se crea una nueva columna
 df['rand_sample'] = sample_values
```

Comment: Gracias no sé si te he entendido, los números deberían seleccionarse de los arrays que ya hay en el dataframe, cada fila/columna tiene un array de len=38000 de ese array debería seleccionar 1000 cifras aleatoriamente.

Comment: He editado la pregunta, el caso sería después de seleccionar los números aleatorios de cada array asignarles una columna nueva en el dataframe. Gracias por la ayuda!